# filter is not an event in icollectionview

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

I am building a filteredComboBox in WPF based on the code [here](http://dotbay.blogspot.com/2009/04/building-filtered-combobox-for-wpf.html)

I have converted the code to VB.Net, as that is what the project is using. The code in use has a call to add a handler on a property, and it doesn't work. I have not done much of this style code in a long time and am a bit lost. Any ideas what may be attempted here to straighten this out?

This is the original segment of C#

```
protected override void OnItemsSourceChanged(IEnumerable oldValue, IEnumerable newValue)
        {
            if (newValue != null)
            {
                ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(newValue);
                view.Filter += this.FilterPredicate;
            }

            if (oldValue != null)
            {
                ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(oldValue);
                view.Filter -= this.FilterPredicate;
            }

            base.OnItemsSourceChanged(oldValue, newValue);
        }
```

This is the converted VB

```
<summary>
 Keep the filter if the ItemsSource is explicitly changed.
 </summary>
 <param name="oldValue">The previous value of the filter.</param>
 <param name="newValue">The current value of the filter.</param>

Protected Overrides Sub OnItemsSourceChanged(oldValue As IEnumerable, newValue As IEnumerable)
    If newValue IsNot Nothing Then
        'Dim view As ICollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(newValue)
        ' AddHandler view.Filter, AddressOf Me.FilterPredicate

        AddHandler CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(newValue).Filter, AddressOf Me.FilterPredicate
    End If

    If oldValue IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim view As ICollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(oldValue)
        RemoveHandler view.Filter, AddressOf Me.FilterPredicate
    End If

    MyBase.OnItemsSourceChanged(oldValue, newValue)
End Sub
```

The error is "Filter is not an event of 'System.ComponentModel.ICollectionView'.

Comment: It's not an event, it's a property.  Which part of the question has to do with c#?

Comment: I am aware it's a property, I am re-using example code that is intended to work, and is written originally in c# (see the link to it's full code)

Comment: Converting bad code does not make good code. If you know it's a Property then use it the way it's intended to.

Comment: After your edit I see the problem.  The C# is code is adding a callback, and the VB code is adding an event handler.  Two different things.

Comment: Should the FilterPredicate be declared as a delegate then? Currently the VB that I get from the C# declares it as a normal function that returns Boolean.

Comment: @DanWier, it's not necessary.  And remember that the article you are using as a model is from the .NET 2.5 era. But in all events, it's not going to work unless you use it as a callback.

Answer (score 1):

Since filter is a property in ICollectionView, you may not attach the event like original CollectionView. so you can point to the predicate method directly

eg. via linq

```
view.Filter = Function(item) CType(item, YourClass).Check
```

sample for your case

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnItemsSourceChanged(oldValue As IEnumerable, newValue As IEnumerable)
    If newValue IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim view As ICollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(newValue)

        'assign predicate method
        view.Filter= AddressOf Me.FilterPredicate
    End If

    If oldValue IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim view As ICollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(oldValue)

        'unassign predicate
        view.Filter = Nothing
    End If

    MyBase.OnItemsSourceChanged(oldValue, newValue)
End Sub
```